# custom blade command in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create directive in laravel5's blade similar self blade as below that capture content of betwen @X and @endX:

```
@can('blablabla')
    <h3>xxxxxxx</h3>
@endcan
```

in fact i want helper that if return true show content of betwen @X and @endX

for example:

```
@if(a==10)
  <h3>sssss</h3>
```

Comment: Was there something unclear about [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#extending-blade)? Was there something in particular you were having trouble with?

Comment: documentation did not help me,did not say anything about my problem